# SwiftUI: Pass value to and use it in init of child view

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding

I've been trying to create a small calendar app with SwiftUI and ran into some issues while trying to pass a value to a child view and use it in its init.

My code looks like this:

ContentView (parent view):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedMonth: Date
    
    var body: some View {
        MonthGridView(selectedMonth: $selectedMonth)
    }
}
```

MonthGridView (child view):

```
struct MonthGridView: View {
    @Binding private var selectedMonth: Date
    var days: [Int]
    
    //this is the part where I'm having troubles
    init(selectedMonth: Binding<Date>) {
        self._selectedMonth = selectedMonth
        days = dayIndices(currentMonth: $selectedMonth) //custom function, also in this line is the error right now
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        //code
    }
}
```

I have looked through a lot of posts on here and a wide variety of tutorials and this is what I came up with. I've tried moving some code around, but wasn't able to get it fully working. I imagine the problem is somewhere around the init, maybe about the Binding wrapper, but I was unable to find information about how to unwrap it.

Appreciate any help getting this working.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I'm guessing (since you haven't included the code) that `dayIndices` doesn't take a Binding -- it probably just takes a `Date`. So, you'd probably want to use `selectedMonth.wrappedValue` instead of `$selectedMonth`

Comment: @jnpdx thank you so much! This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Never found anything like .wrappedValue, but it seems to work (i might need to figure out some logic errors, but at least no syntax anymore!)

Answer (score 2):

It'll be easier to understand the problem if we “de-sugar” the `@Binding` property wrapper. When you say this:

```
@Binding private var selectedMonth: Date
```

Swift translates that into this:

```
private var _selectedMonth: Binding<Date>

private var $selectedMonth: Date { _selectedMonth.projectedValue }

private var selectedDate: Date {
    get { _selectedMonth.wrappedValue }
    nonmutating set { _selectedMonth.wrappedValue }
}
```

Here is your `init` again:

```
init(selectedMonth: Binding<Date>) {
    self._selectedMonth = selectedMonth
    days = dayIndices(currentMonth: $selectedMonth) //custom function, also in this line is the error right now
}
```

You're using `$selectedMonth` before `days` has been initialized. But as I showed above, `$selectedMonth` is a *computed property*. You are not allowed to call any methods on `self` before `self` is fully initialized, and the getter of a computed property counts as a method.

In general, you can work around the limitation by accessing `_selectedMonth.projectedValue` directly:

```
    days = dayIndices(currentMonth: _selectedMonth.projectedValue)
```

However, in this case, all of `_selectedMonth`, `_selectedMonth.projectedValue`, and the `init` parameter `selectedMonth` are the same `Binding`, you can use any of them directly. So either of these will also work:

```
    days = dayIndices(currentMonth: selectedMonth)
    days = dayIndices(currentMonth: _selectedMonth)
```